# Prove $f:GL(n,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ defined by $f(x):=x^{-1}$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity, matrix-calculus

I have to prove that $f:GL(n,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ defined by $f(x):=x^{-1}$ is continuous. What I have so far:

Consider $Inc \circ f: GL(n,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, where $Inc$ is the inclusion map from $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ into $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. Throughout we take the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ and the relative topology on $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$. I've managed to prove that $Inc$ is continuous, $Inc \circ f$ continuous  $\iff f$ continuous and that $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.

How can I use this information to prove that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: The way I would do it is to use the well-known fact that the coefficients of the inverse matrix are a polynomial function of the starting matrix.

Comment: I know how to do it this way, but I have to use topological arguments to prove this?

Comment: you mean that you need a homeomorphism between $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and $\mathbb R^{n^2}$?

Comment: Are we not trying to prove that $f$ is a homeomorphism between $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$?

Comment: Kramer's rule for the determinant is a rational function in the coefficients of a matrix. This leads to formulas for the coefficients of $x^{-1}$ that are rational functions of the coefficients of $x$. Rational functions are continuous. You ask "but I have to use topological arguments to prove this?" The $\epsilon$-$\delta$ arguments of multivariable calculus used to prove that rational functions are continuous **are** topological arguments.

Comment: @jackwo: I am not sure if it can be done. But, it is surely unnecessary. The map $\mathbb R^{n\times n}\ni X \mapsto (X_{1,1}, \dotsc X_{n, 1}, \dotsc, X_{1,n}, \dotsc X_{n, n})$ is a homeomorphism (bi-continuous function) from $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ to $\mathbb R^{n^2}$.

Comment: We got told in lectures that this was the way to prove it, but I'm not convinced? If we let $U$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, then $Inc^{-1}(U)=U\cap GL(n,\mathbb{R})$, but then why is $f^{-1}$ of this open in $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @jackwo -- you mean some subset of $R^{n^2}$, yes? ($GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is not connected for $n\geq 1$)

Comment: @uniquesolution -- Yes sorry, I meant a subset. I have proved that $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is not connected actually! But why does this prove that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: @jackwo -- It doesn't; it just pointed out that $GL(n,R)$ is not homeomorphic to $R^{n^2}$, which you probably know anyhow. Anyway, I don't see how you can use only the topology of $R^{n^2}$ to get continuity of the inverse.

Comment: In that case I'm not sure what to do. What do you think would be the best way to word the fact that coefficients of the inverse matrix are a polynomial function of the original matrix? Thanks for the help everyone, by the way! Really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use
$$
A^{-1}-B^{-1}=A^{-1}(B-A)B^{-1}
$$
and the sub-multiplicativity of (most of) the standard norms.

---

Since that goes too fast, use the Neumann series as in
$$
B^{-1}=A^{-1}(I-X)^{-1}=A^{-1}(I+X+X^2+X^3+…)
$$
leading to
$$
\|B^{-1}-A^{-1}\|\le\frac{\|X\|}{1-\|X\|}
$$
where $X=I-BA^{-1}$ and thus $\|X\|\le\|A^{-1}\|·\|A-B\|$. Which is valid as long as $\|B-A\|\le\|A^{-1}\|^{-1}$.

Comment: It is enough to prove continuity at $I$, i.e. you may simplify taking $A=I$.

Comment: Why does this prove that $f$ is continuous? Also doesn't $(I-X)^{-1}=(I+X+X^{2}+...)$ rely on the fact that $\parallel X \parallel <1$?

Comment: This is exactly what the facts about $X$ at the end say: The inequality above proves local Lipschitz-continuity in the ball given by the last formula which is contained in the set $\|X\|=\|I-BA^{-1}\|<1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use Cayley-Hamilton theorem to show that $A^{-1}$ is a polynomial of $A$.

Comment: It's not a polynomial, it's a rational function of entries of matrix $A$.

Comment: Yes, but only if we look at the coefficient of that polynomial as (continuous) functions of $A$.